# journalctl -f with journal-remote - not reading all files in /var/log/journal/remote/

Tags: systemd-journald

Using journald-upload and journald-remote.

I need to receive journal entries from multiple systems. I have configured both sending & receiving services and they appear to function correctly, in that if I follow a specified remote journal

(using journalctl -f --file /var/log/journal/remote/), I get each journal entry reported as it occurs on the remote machine. However, if I use journalctl -f -D /var/log/journal/remote/, I only get one of the remote files output from journalctl.

I've tried each of the remote files individually & they work, but if I try to follow all of them, either merged or not, I only get one of them.OS is Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

If I run a separate instance of journalctl simultaneously, pointing to the specific files in /var/log/journal/remote, each instance reports updates as they occur on the remote machines.

I also tried stopping the sending & receiving services, deleted all the file sin the /var/log/journal/remote directory, then restarted all of it. The files were recreated for each of the remote machines, but the overall behavior did not change. In fact, the same machine was followed by journalctl as before.

Thank for any pointers.

Comment: Workaround: Most bugs in journalctl file handling go away when querying `_MACHINE_ID=uuid` individually after deleting any empty files left from crashing journald.